# How debuggers can trace the stack?

Tags: windows, stack, reverse-engineering, trace

I was trying to implement a stack tracer, using stack pointers; RSP and RBP, but I think debuggers use an entirely different way to grab the return addresses, or maybe I am missing something. I can grab the return address of the last stack frame, but I can't get the others because I don't know the size of other stack frames, so I can't figure out how much bytes should I go back from stack frame, to get the return address. Are there anybody know which way do debuggers use to trace stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to trace the stack when the code uses frame pointers. In this case `ebp/rbp` is used as the frame pointer and functions begin with prologs and end with epilogs.
A typical prolog looks like this:

```
push    rbp       ; save previous frame pointer
mov     rbp, rsp  ; initialize this functions frame pointer
```

A typical epilog looks like this:

```
mov     rsp, rbp  ; restore the value of rsp
pop     rbp       ; restore previous frame pointer value from stack
retn
```

Thus in every place in a function `rbp` points to the stack position where the previous frame pointer is saved and `rbp+8` contains the saved return address.
To get the called function a debugger should read `[rbp+8]` value and find a function to which this address belongs. This can be done by searching in debugging symbols.
Next it should read `[rbp]` value to get the frame pointer of the caller function. Continue this process until you find a toplevel function. This is typically a system library function that starts threads.

Comment: Oh cool. I never thought like that. Thanks